# NMaximize : constraint violation

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
NMinimize[{x^2 + (y - .5)^2, y >= 0 && y >= x + 1}, {x, y}]
NMinimize[{x^2 + (y - .5)^2, y >= 0, y >= x + 1}, {x, y}]
NMinimize[{x^2 + (y - .5)^2, {y >= 0, y >= x + 1}}, {x, y}]
NMinimize[{x^2 + (y - .5)^2, {y >= 0 && y >= x + 1}}, {x, y}]
```

All above runs fine. I think the 'cons' are exactly the same.But is there any 'reason' for using a particular way to write constraints?

Not that I dont want to put a minimal example, but I don't think I can upload a CSV file here. (or I dont know how.) But check this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*4C*)

FourC[xij_] := 
    Module[{phiL, phiH, pL, pH, K, ind, fi, li, j, ans1, ans2, ans3, 
    ans4, ans}, K = Length[xij];
    phiL = Table[1/(1 + Exp[-Subscript[\[Phi], j]]), {j, 1, K - 1}];
    phiH = Table[
    1/(1 + Exp[-Subscript[\[Phi], j] - 
    Subscript[\[Eta], \[Phi]]]), {j, 1, K - 1}];
    phiL = Append[phiL, 0];
    phiH = Append[phiH, 0];
    pL = Table[1/(1 + Exp[-Subscript[p, j]]), {j, 2, K}];
    pH = Table[
    1/(1 + Exp[-Subscript[p, j] - Subscript[\[Eta], p]]), {j, 2, K}];
    pL = Prepend[pL, 1];
    pH = Prepend[pH, 1];
    fi = First[Position[xij, 1]][[1]];
    li = Last[Position[xij, 1]][[1]];

    ans1 = w1*
    Sum[Product[phiL[[j]], {j, fi, d - 1}]*(1 - phiL[[d]])*
    Product[pL[[j]]^xij[[j]]*(1 - pL[[j]])^(1 - xij[[j]]), {j, 
    fi + 1, d}], {d, li, K}];

    ans2 = w2*
    Sum[Product[phiL[[j]], {j, fi, d - 1}]*(1 - phiL[[d]])*
    Product[pH[[j]]^xij[[j]]*(1 - pH[[j]])^(1 - xij[[j]]), {j, 
    fi + 1, d}], {d, li, K}];

    ans3 = w3*
    Sum[Product[phiH[[j]], {j, fi, d - 1}]*(1 - phiH[[d]])*
    Product[pL[[j]]^xij[[j]]*(1 - pL[[j]])^(1 - xij[[j]]), {j, 
    fi + 1, d}], {d, li, K}];

    ans4 = (1 - w1 - w2 - w3)*
    Sum[Product[phiH[[j]], {j, fi, d - 1}]*(1 - phiH[[d]])*
    Product[pH[[j]]^xij[[j]]*(1 - pH[[j]])^(1 - xij[[j]]), {j, 
    fi + 1, d}], {d, li, K}];


    ans = ans1 + ans2 + ans3 + ans4
]

data = Import["female_unique_sort.csv", "CSV"];
xij = data[[All, 1 ;; 9]];
feq = data[[All, 10]];

kappa = FourC[#] & /@ xij;
loglik = feq.Log[kappa];
pars = Variables[Level[kappa, {-2}]]
Length[pars]

cons = {
    Subscript[\[Eta], \[Phi]] >= 0,
    Subscript[\[Eta], p] >= 0,
    0 < w1 < 1,
    0 < w2 < 1,
    0 < w3 < 1,
    0 < w1 + w2 + w3 < 1
}

ans = NMaximize[
    {loglik, cons}, pars
]
```

This is the full code. And when it runs, it has a warning:
[image]

Clearly, it's trying something, that does not satisfy the constraints `(0<w1+w2+w3<1)`. 
I am not sure whether it stopped due to the violation (of the function value not being a real number) OR it stopped because the optimization is done, and the warning is just to note.

But I am really confused by the ways to input constraints. Is there a way to force these constraints, BEFORE it evaluates the 'loglik' (target function)?

Thanks!

Comment: You are neither showing complete input nor output. Impossible to say what might be going on, or whether it is expected behavior.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry if that was not clear for you. My main question is, I want to know, how to put constraints 'correctly'. The screenshot should have shown that `[Out12]` is the 'cons', I put. But during the optimization, it is using the values, w1+w2+w3>1. That is something I don't quit understand. How should I put constraints correctly? Is there a way to upload CSV file?So I can use my full example. Hope you would get what I am asking for. Thanks.

Comment: I think your constraints are probably being interpreted correctly. Generally one should use either a list or a conjunction (your second variant has both), but it will probably get parsed regardless.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Assuming all the ways are acceptable, why during the optimization, it would evaluate the function, when the constraint 0<w1+w2+w3<1 is NOT true? That's why I am confused.

Comment: @Artes I dont think it's a duplicate. In my case, the relationship is not exactly equivalent. I can't replace w3=1-w1-w2 as this is not true in this case.

Comment: To repeat what I already said, it is not possible for me to ascertain what might be going on since you have not shown complete code (a common reason for questions getting closed, I might add).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am not trying to hide the full code. But I understand the usually, a minimal working example should be given. Which I think I have used the top few lines, to ask more directly, what my confusion is. I have given the full code now, but again, without the data (.CSV), I am not sure how much use it would be. But I do find it harsh to close the question since it is clearly a different matter. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the issue is the same as for the proposed duplicate of @Artes, to wit, that the penalty used to enforce the nonrectangular constraint (the last one) is not entirely preventing it from having a small violation. A way to work around that might be to change the objective to have an explicit `Re[...]` or `Abs[...]` (if appropriate), or something along those lines.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, `Re[]` does works for this example in particular. I am not trying to be picky or annoying. However, as a new leaner, I still couldn't understand the 'right'(proper) way to write down constraints. Those top lines I have show, are actually given as examples in MMA 10 help at various places for optimization examples. The syntax given for the command `?NMaximize` suggest we use NMaximize[{function, constraints},{pars}]. But accident, I have used cons={} to create constraints. Also, NMaximize[{function, cons},{pars}] ran without problems sometimes, but not all the time.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Basically, when I create constraints like a table{}. To put them into `NMaximize`, I should lose the brackets. That's what I can understand.

Comment: You can put the constraints in as a list (`Table` result). So `NMaximize[{obj, {c1,c2,...}}, vars]` is fine. Other variants work also.